# oracle sql find max size in byte a column can hold

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to find the max size(in byte) a column can hold so that I could know the max size (in byte) of a data row in the table.

Thank You

Comment: The number of bytes used for a number varies but has an upper limit; the max number of bytes used for a varchar2 column with character semantics depends on the character set, so unless you have byte semantics it's not as simple as you might think. Why do you need to know the internal storage requirements? (Depending on what you're doing, the dba_tables.avg_row_len might be useful, but obviously isn't the max - of the current values, never mind what's possible)

Comment: Why do you think you need that information? What is the underlying problem you are trying solve with that? The max. (actual) size of rows in a table can easily be calculated using `select max(vsize(col_1) + vsize(col_2) + vsize(col_3)) from the_table`

Comment: Thank You for your response. Where I work, we are implementing a new program. So, I need to estimate the size each table might need to store certain amount of data. The amount of data is uncertain, it can be in thousand/millions, so I am estimating for about 20 million. Therefore, based on max-size a single data row can hold, how much space will be required to hold 20 mil.

Comment: How many of your rows will max out the length of each column though? A average row length might be more useful, if you have appropriate data to get that estimate from. ([This might be interesting](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:302216525000), and you can search for other ways to estimate size. And don't forget indexes!)